# QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection Hibernate Select w/subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I'm new to hibernate and having a hard time understanding HQL. Below is my DAO, which is returning the Query Exception. I'd really appreciate any help on this, I've been through this site and the official docs and still can't make it work. Thanks!!

FYI: mapping is .xml and cannot be switched to JPA

Stack Trace:

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [feature0_.id.actors] with element property reference [name] [SELECT f from ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Feature as f where f.name like :term or f.actors.name like :term or f.genre.name like :term order by f.name ASC ]

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [feature0_.id.actors] with element property reference [name] [SELECT f from ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Feature as f where f.name like :term or f.actors.name like :term or f.genre.name like :term order by f.name ASC ]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [feature0_.id.actors] with element property reference [name] [SELECT f from ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Feature as f where f.name like :term or f.actors.name like :term or f.genre.name like :term order by f.name ASC ]
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode$1.buildIllegalCollectionDereferenceException(DotNode.java:68)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.checkLhsIsNotCollection(DotNode.java:550)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:246)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:118)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:114)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:881)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1264)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4297)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3913)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1947)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1900)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1897)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:794)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:595)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:219)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:197)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1736)
    ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.FeatureDAO.search(FeatureDAO.java:98)
    ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.FeatureDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3247faf2.invoke(<generated>)
    net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.dao.FeatureDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f55db758.search(<generated>)
    ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.controller.AppController.buscar(AppController.java:229)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.37 logs.
```

HBM Feature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Qualified Class Names -->
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
<class name="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Feature" table="feature">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="feature_type" type="string"/>
    <property name="name" column="name"/>
    <property name="runtime" column="runtime"/>
    <property name="coverImage" column="cover_image"/>
    <property name="storyline" column="storyline"/> 
    <set name="showtimes" inverse="true" cascade="all" fetch="join">
        <key column="feature_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Showtime" entity-name="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Showtime"/>
    </set>        
    <subclass name="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Movie" discriminator-value="M">
        <set name="actors" inverse="true" cascade="all" fetch="join">
            <key column="feature_id"/>
            <one-to-many class="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Actor" entity-name="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Actor"/>
        </set>      
    </subclass>
        <subclass name="ar.edu.uces.progweb2.springmvc.model.Documentary"  discriminator-value="D">
        <many-to-one name="genre" 
        column="documentary_genre_id"
        not-null="true" fetch="join"/>  
    </subclass>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Model Classes (Feature, Movie, Documentary)

Feature:

```
public abstract class Feature {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int runtime;
    private byte[] coverImage;
    private String storyline;
    private String featureType;
    private Set<Showtime> showtimes;

    public abstract boolean isMovie();      
    public abstract boolean isDocumentary();

    public Feature(){
        this.showtimes = new HashSet<Showtime>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRuntime() {
        return runtime;
    }

    public void setRuntime(int runtime) {
        this.runtime = runtime;
    }

    public byte[] getCoverImage() {
        return coverImage;
    }

    public void setCoverImage(byte[] coverImage) {
        this.coverImage = coverImage;
    }

    public String getStoryline() {
        return storyline;
    }

    public void setStoryline(String storyline) {
        this.storyline = storyline;
    }

    public String getFeatureType() {
        return featureType;
    }

    public void setFeatureType(String featureType) {
        this.featureType = featureType;
    }

    public Set<Showtime> getShowtimes() {
        return showtimes;
    }
    public void setShowtimes(Set<Showtime> showtimes) {
        this.showtimes = showtimes;
    }
}
```

Movie:

```
public class Movie extends Feature {

    private Set<Actor> actors;

    @Override
    public boolean isMovie() {
        return true;
    }

    public Movie (){
        actors = new HashSet<Actor>();
    }
}
```

Documentary:

```
public class Documentary extends Feature{

    private Genre genre;

    @Override
    public boolean isDocumentary(){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMovie() {
        return false;
    }

    public Documentary(){
        this.genre = new Genre();
    }

    public Genre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }       

}
```

DAO:

```
public List<Feature> search(SearchForm sf){
        StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("SELECT f ");
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        switch (sf.getFeatureType()){   //0: Both, 1: Commercial Film, 2: Documentary
        case 0:
            query.append("from Feature as f "); 
            if (sf.getTerm() != null && !sf.getTerm().isEmpty()){
                query.append("where f.name like :term or f.actors.name like :term or f.genre.name like :term ");
                params.put("term","%"+ sf.getTerm() + "%");
            }
            break;
        case 1:         
            if (sf.getTerm() != null && !sf.getTerm().isEmpty()){
                query.append("from Movie m left join m.actors a where (a.name like :term or m.name like :term) ");
                params.put("term","%"+ sf.getTerm() + "%");
            } else {
                query.append("from Movie m ");
            }
            break;
        case 2:         
            if (sf.getTerm() != null && !sf.getTerm().isEmpty()){
                query.append("from Documentary d left join d.genre g where  (g.name like :term or d.name like :term) ");
                params.put("term", "%"+ sf.getTerm()+"%");
            } else {
                query.append("from Documentary d left join d.genre g "); 
            }
            break;
        }


        switch (sf.getOrder()){
            case "nameDesc":
                query.append("order by f.name DESC ");
                break;

            default:
                query.append("order by f.name ASC ");
                break;
            }

        System.out.println("Query: " + query.toString());
        Query q = session.createQuery(query.toString());
        Iterator<String> iter = params.keySet().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            String k = iter.next();
            Object o = params.get(k);
            q.setParameter(k, o);
        }
        q.setFirstResult(this.resultsPerPage * sf.getPage());
        q.setMaxResults(this.resultsPerPage);
        //System.out.println("Search OK!");
        return q.list();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, my hql is rather sloppy

```
         case 0:
            query.append("from Feature f "); 
            if (sf.getTerm() != null && !sf.getTerm().isEmpty()){
                query.append("left join fetch f.actors a left join f.genre g where f.name like :term or a.name like :term or g.name like :term ");
                params.put("term","%"+ sf.getTerm() + "%");
            }
            break;
```

It's important to think of good alias names for your entities and also learned that such errors are probably related to lack of joins. Thanks!